# Real analysis Textbook

Tags: calculus, analysis

Hi I am taking Real Analysis II, and we are using the Textbook "The Elements of Real Analysis 2nd edtion by R.G.Bartle.  Does anyone know, another textbook that is very very "Identical" to this book and popular analysis book professors use now? Thank you

Comment: Why do you want an *identical* book?

Comment: to read off of, something that correlates well with it, this book is hard to understand

Comment: If you want a book which is "very very identical" to Bartle's book, then isn't such a book going to be just as difficult to understand as Bartle's??

Answer (score 1):

Try [Understanding Analysis](http://community.middlebury.edu/~abbott/UA/UA.html) by Stephen Abbott.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the simplified version **Introduction to Real Analysis**, 4th Edition *Robert G. Bartle, Donald R. Sherbert*, March 2011